# Как продуктивнее делать код-ревью в гитхабе?

Tags: git, github, инспекция-кода

Есть несколько чужих репозиториев над которыми нужно произвести код-ревью.

Как вариант можно комментировать коммиты, но таким образом комменты будут со временем улетать вниз из-за потока новых коммитов. Также можно создать пуллреквест, но вытягивать уже существующий проект.

Есть ли какой-нибудь сервис для код-ревью, который сможет упорядочить тикеты с замечаниями к коду и чтобы остальные видели эти тикеты? И чтобы при этом тикеты можно было закрывать как решенные?

Comment: Оформляйте issue на каждый найденный момент, к которому у вас замечание. Коммиты ревьюить смысла мало, лучше проревьюить текущую версию и потом например пулл реквесты (особенно если напрямую в мастер пушить запретить).

Comment: Просто проблема issue в том, что их потом нельзя будет удалить полностью, они всегда будут отображаться

Comment: А в чём проблема? Более того, к issue можно будет привязывать изменения, сделанные по их замечаниям, что для истории может быть важно.